# Empty excel cells XML parsing issue

Tags: java, xml, excel

I've the code below which reads an excel file into java code and then parses to XML document by creating the appropriate tags. The issue which I'm stuck is the empty cells.
Imagine couple of columns and rows filled with data and in case a cell is blank then it screws up the XML document because in that case it inserts the value of next cell which is not empty hence the result doesn't come up the correct one. Any proposals for the code edit?

```
public class ExcelXMLParser {
public ExcelXMLParser ()  {
}

public void displayFromExcel (String xlsPath)
{
    InputStream inputStream = null; 
    try
    {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream (xlsPath);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("File not found in the specified path.");
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

    POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = null;

    try {
        //Initializing the XML document
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = document.createElement("records");
        document.appendChild(rootElement);


        fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (inputStream);
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt (0); 
        Iterator<?> rows = sheet.rowIterator ();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        while (rows.hasNext ()) 
        {
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next(); 
            int rowNumber = row.getRowNum ();
            // display row number
            //System.out.println ("Row No.: " + rowNumber);

            // get a row, iterate through cells.
            Iterator<?> cells = row.cellIterator (); 

            ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (cells.hasNext ())
            {
                HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();
                switch (cell.getCellType ())
                {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
                {
                    // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                    //System.out.println ("Numeric: " + Integer.toString((int) cell.getNumericCellValue ()));
                    rowData.add(Integer.toString((int) cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                    break;
                }
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :
                {
                    // STRING CELL TYPE
                    HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();

                    //System.out.println ("String: " + richTextString.getString ());
                    rowData.add(richTextString.getString ());
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    // types other than String and Numeric.
                    System.out.println ("Type not supported.");
                    break;
                }
            } // end switch
        } // end while
        data.add(rowData);
    } //end while

    int numOfData = data.size();

    for (int i = 1; i < numOfData; i++){
        Element dataElement = document.createElement("data");
        rootElement.appendChild(dataElement);

        int index = 0;
        for(String s: data.get(i)) {
            String headerString = data.get(0).get(index);
            Element headerElement = document.createElement(headerString);
            dataElement.appendChild(headerElement);
            System.out.println(headerElement);
            System.out.println(s);
            headerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
            index++;
        }
    }

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

    //Add indentation to output
    transformer.setOutputProperty
    (OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(
            "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

    // Define source
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("c:\\Users\\Temped\\Desktop\\dataXML.xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);

}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    System.out.println("ParserConfigurationException " + e.getMessage());
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    System.out.println("TransformerConfigurationException "+ e.getMessage());
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    System.out.println("TransformerException " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    ExcelXMLParser generateOutput = new ExcelXMLParser ();
    String xlsPath ="C:\\Users\\Temped\\Desktop\\dataXLS.xls";
    generateOutput.displayFromExcel (xlsPath);
}   
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple as adding and empty string to your rowdata in the default of your switch?

Comment: That doesn't fix I think..

Comment: Well, if you want to mirror the layout of your excel sheet 1:1, you have to make a node for every cell. And that would do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using Maps. By creating Map lists with the help of LinkedHashMap.